# Thomas algorithm (Numerical methods)

Tags: numerical-methods

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idN4C.png)

Please help i've been trying to solve it since 2 days.I have solved it using the differential equation but answer is coming different from thomas algo. and DE.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that Thomas algorithm is just an improved way of applying Gaussian elimination to a tridiagonal linear system. With such a huge value for $\Delta x$ you will necessarily get big errors with respect to the exact solution (unless the exact solution is a polynomial with degree $\leq$ than the precision of the finite difference formulas being used).

If you implemented the problem in matlab or equivalent, just run your code for smaller and smaller $\Delta x$ and observe if the numerical solution is approaching the exact solution.